# Updating NDArray in deeplearn.js

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have the following array:

```
x_poly = dl.NDArray.zeros([2, 4], 'int32');
```

I want to update the first column of the matrix `x_poly` with a vector. I can do this on Octave using:

```
x_poly = zeros(2,4);
x_poly(:, 1) = [4; 5];
```

**How can I do this in deeplearn.js?**

The [documentation](https://deeplearnjs.org/docs/api/classes/ndarray.html#set) shows `set` method can update a single element on the NDArray object by provided number.